# Polymer 1.0 input validity observer

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

I'm having some trouble watching for changes to input validity in polymer 1.0.  More precisely, an observer function that should fire on any changes to the bound 'invalid' property is not firing as I'd expect it to.  For instance, the function may fire when the control first becomes invalid, but if becomes valid again, the observer function is not being triggered (invalid not becoming false?).  In my current example, I happen to be utilizing Polymer 1.0's ***gold-email-input*** element as follows:

Extract from my custom element's local DOM template:

```
<paper-icon-item>
      <iron-icon icon="social:person"></iron-icon>
      <gold-email-input id="userEmail" bind-value="{{userEmail}}" required auto-validate invalid="{{invalidEmail}}" error-message="Invalid email address"></gold-email-input>
</paper-icon-item>
```

Extract from my custom element's script declaration:

```
properties: {
      invalidEmail: {type: Boolean, observer: 'emailValidityChanged'}
}

emailValidityChanged: function(newVal, oldVal) {
      console.log(this.nodeName + " emailValidityChanged observer fired\n"); 
}
```

I'm probably missing something straightforward here?  I've also tried observing changes on the `userEmail` property, and then checking the state of `this.$.userEmail.invalid` within the observer function, to no avail. It does appear that the `invalid` property is not being reset when the entry becomes valid. Any suggestions?  Maybe another approach altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be a bug - I've created a [new issue](https://github.com/PolymerElements/gold-email-input/issues/26) to seek clarification with the project owners on expected behavior. Currently, it seems that `invalid` is set up as a one-way bind from host to child, but I thought it shouldn't be. I can get your snippet working by making changes to `paper-input-behavior`, `paper-input-container` and `gold-email-input`, but until the project owners clarify on what `invalid` is really used for, don't.

As a workaround, use `MutationObservers` instead.

```
<template>
    My Email: <span>{{myEmail}}</span><br>
    Validity: <span>{{validity}}</span><br>
    <gold-email-input id="foo" bind-value="{{myEmail}}" required
                      auto-validate error-message="Invalid email address">
    </gold-email-input>
</template>

<script>
    ...
      attached: function () {
        var t = this;
        var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
          mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
            if (mutation.target.classList.contains("is-invalid")) {
              // stuff to do when email is invalid
              t.validity = "No, email is invalid";

            } else {
              // stuff to do when email is valid
              t.validity = "Yes, email is valid";

            }
          });
        });
        var node = this.$.foo.$.container.$$(".add-on-content");
        observer.observe(node, {
          attributes: true,
          attributeFilter: ["class"]
        });
      }
    ...
</script>
```

<s>Working Jsbin: http://jsbin.com/resokidako/edit?html,output</s>

**Update 1**

Observe the `add-on-content` node instead.

Updated Jsbin: http://jsbin.com/wivimovufi/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Thanks for your help @zerodevx.  I'll monitor the GitHub issue you created.  I think it is a bug as well.  Your workaround does the trick for the most part.  However, I noted that if you add the `required` attribute to the input, upon the control first receiving focus the mutation observer does not determine validity appropriately.

Comment: No problems at all - I'm using this component in my project as well. I get what you're saying - I'll edit my answer to tie the observer to the error message node itself. In that case, as long the component's in-built validation updates, the mutation will be reflected.

Comment: Perfect!  VERY much appreciated!